# Find $A$, such that $E=\{(w_1,w_2)\in \mathbb{T}^2: w_1/w_2 \in A \}$ is not almost-open

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathbb{T}$ denote the unit circle on complex plane.
Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{T}$ be given, define $E=\{(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in \mathbb{T}^2:\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}\in A\}$.

Question:
**Does there exists** a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{T}$, such that

1. $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.
2. $E$ **can’t** be written as $E=U\Delta N$, where $U$ is open and $N$ is null(with Lebesgue measure). Here $\Delta$ Means symmetry difference: $U\Delta N=(U-N)\cup(N-U)$.

---

My thought: consider $\phi:\mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2;(\omega_1,\omega_2)\mapsto (\omega_1/\omega_2,\omega_2)$, which is a continuous group isomorphism. And it is corresponding to the lift $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2;(x,y)\mapsto (x-y,y)$. So $m_2(V)=cm_2(\Phi(V))$ for all measurable set $V\subseteq \mathbb{T}^2$, $c>0$ comes from Jaccobi. So if $E=U\Delta N$, I wish that $A\times\mathbb{T}=\Phi(E)=\Phi(U)\Delta \Phi(N)$. And want to conclude something from this. For example, something like $A$ can be written as a symmetry difference of open subset and null subset of $\mathbb{T}$.

Any help or hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $A$ a closed nowhere dense subset with positive Lebesgue measure. Then $A\times \mathbb{T}$ is also a closed nowhere dense subset of $\mathbb{T^2}$ with positive 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure. As in my post, $A\times \mathbb{T}=\Phi(U)\Delta\Phi(N)$ But $\Phi$ is homemorphisms and keep null set. So $A\times\mathbb{T}$ is a symmetry difference of an open set and a null set.

An easy exercise: any symmetry difference of an open set and a null set can’t be closed nowhere dense with positive measure.